# .NET string.Compare, String.Compare and string.CompareTo anomalous behavior

Tags: .net, compare, string-comparison

Before replying please note, I'm not interested in comments such as "Don't do this, use equals, or some other method". The point here is to understand the peculiarity of string.Compare and String.CompareTo. From a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8020426/3297640) it looks like Compare implements System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare, which produces identical results as shown below.

Here is my C# code is for both Compare and CompareOrdinal results for various combination of strings.

```
        foreach (var item1 in new String []{ "John", "J", "john", "j"})
        {
            foreach (var item2 in new String[] { "John", "J", "john", "j" })
            {
                if (item1!=item2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("({0,-12}{1,6},{2,6}", item1+","+item2+"):", 
                        string.CompareOrdinal(item1,item2), string.Compare(item1,item2));
                }
            }
        }
```

While CompareOrdinal gives correct results, the Compare has results inconsistent [with the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx) in cases marked with "<<<". In the first marked result, Compare is indicating that "John" follows "john" in the sort order. I don't see how that is possible with my current culture (US-En). Am I missing something here?

```
(John,J):       111,     1
(John,john):    -32,     1  <<<
(John,j):       -32,     1  <<<
(J,John):      -111,    -1
(J,john):       -32,    -1
(J,j):          -32,     1  <<<
(john,John):     32,    -1  <<<
(john,J):        32,     1
(john,j):       111,     1
(j,John):        32,    -1  <<<
(j,J):           32,    -1  <<<
(j,john):      -111,    -1
```

Comment: Hello - I've not heard from anyone in the community. Can anyone think of why think of a reason behind this implementation? This looks like a bug to me and I will be reporting it unless someone can come up with an answer.